# run a npx from plist of global daemons of mac os m1

Tags: macos, plist, root, launch, daemons

this is what i want to run
its test on cypress that runs four times in a day to do something in another webpage for me
there is not possible to run npm or npx from plist to lauchdaemon or launchagents ?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change working directory to where your Cypress tests are located
cd /Users/codyzzd/Meus\ Documentos/code7/

# Run Cypress with the desired command
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/pontomais.cy.js"
```

and this is the plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ponto.pontomais</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <!--<string>/bin/sh</string>-->
     <string>/Users/codyzzd/shponto.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.ponto.pontomais.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.ponto.pontomais.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
 
    <array>

        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>13</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>23</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>13</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>13</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>4</integer>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>12</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>13</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>17</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>5</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

i create a sh that runs npx but when i am on plist

he show this
/Users/codyzzd/shponto.sh: line 7: npx: command not found

Comment: At least the script of a global daemon or agent must be located at the  local domain and must have appropriate access privileges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.